# how migrate to Gemini 5 .net API

Tags: gemini

I have a tool that communicates with Gemini platform using .net API 
CounterSoft.Gemini.Commons, Version 4.0.1.3038
Assembly CounterSoft.Gemini.WebServices, Version 4.0.1.3038

Now Gemini is going to be updated on the site I'm connecting with. AFAIU I have to update .net Gemini API wrappers too.

The problem is that API has been changed and it is a little bit tricky to find method in the new version.

Is there any howto guide? 
I've checked http://docs.countersoft.com/rest-api/ but unable to find replacement for IssuesService.GetMyWork() method. In 4th version it return all issues that belongs to current user. I've tried to use Reflector but it fails to find something like GetMyWork method

Regards,
oleksa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to go through the same process and couldn't find a guide for it. However, what we did for "My Work" is use the GetFilteredItems method and passed in the resource in the filter:

```
IssuesFilter filter = new IssuesFilter();
filter.Resources = "1"; // Your user id
var myItems = service.ItemService.GetFilteredItems(filter);
```